# how to set the cursor position in a non textbox component

Tags: c#

I am working with a component named SpinEdit that has a text property. how would I set the cursor position in this component ?

Comment: There are lots of controls out there called SpinEdit - which suite of controls is it from?

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless it exposes a `SelectionStart` property, or similar.

The `Text` property is a string, which bears no relation to the cursor within the editor.

If it does expose a `SelectionStart` property, then you can usually get and set that to get and set the cursor index within the control programatically.

In response to your comment, you set the `SelectionStart` property of most controls that have it by giving it an `int` value. For example, to set the cursor to the start of the Control:

```
Control.SelectionStart = 0;
```

To set the cursor to the end of the control:

```
Control.SelectionStart = Control.Text.Length -1;
```

But, these **will only work if** the control you are using has the property and allows it to be set. You've not specified where the control comes from, so until you give us more information, there's nothing else we can do to help.

Comment: this what i am asking for... how to set it programatically?

Comment: @Strider007: in order to get an answer of that, I would help if you revealed exactly *which* SpinEdit control that you are using, and in what environment (ASP.NET/WinForms/WPF/Silverlight). If you edit and update your original question with these details, you will increase your chance of getting the information that you are looking for.

Comment: I am using SpinEdit that is inherited from IntegerInput. Also I am working with WPF.